# Problem when executing an asynchronous code in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, async-await, sqflite

Can anyone help me how `async` and `await` work? The program complains that `db` is `null` when calling `rawQuery(...)`. What I understood is the next statements after `await` won't be executed when function with `await` is not done yet, but the statements after an `async` functions won't wait for that function to finish its job. For example:

```
var db;

Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    ...
    List<Map<String, Object>> resultSet;
    asyncFunction();
    db.rawQuery(...).then((value) => resultSet = value);
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(...),
        child: Text()
    );
     
}

void asyncFunction() async {
    String dbPath = await getDatabasesPath();
    String path = join(dbPath, 'sample.db');
    db = await openDatabase(path);
}
```

`db` is `null` in `db.rawQuery(...)`. (I hope you get my point). I don't know if it is possible to put `return Scaffold()` inside `then(...)` or is it possible for `Widget build() {...}` to wait till all data are ready.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT : Sorry, I didn't noticed that you were in the build method of a widget.

Firstly, if you call your database here, you'll call your database **EVERY TIME** your widget re-build. That's not a good practice. You need to instanciate your database somewhere else (in a service for example). Once your data is load you can call it here.

Secondly, if you want to show data from a Future. You need to use a [FutureBuilder](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html), as @jamesdlin said.

Comment: having an `async` in `build()` the compilers tells me that the `build()` function should return a `Future`

Comment: [Use a `FutureBuilder`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63017280/).  BTW, `asyncFunction` should return a `Future<void>` for callers to properly `await` it.

Comment: @NarutoUzumaki I have update my answer, you can process like that. By the way, if you know the type of your db var, you can replace 'dynamic' by the right type :)